Not able to make more than 6 https or http requests to envoy proxy server that send them to grpc backend server
I am making grpc https requests from my web browser to grpc backend service using envoy proxy server. The back end function I am hitting is a grpc server side streaming function. Now when I am opening the web page in multiple tabs and opening multiple server side streaming after making 6 parallel connections, the 7th request is going into pending state.
Can someone tell me why this is happening and is there a solution for this issue?
Below is the envoy file I am using:
static_resources:
  listeners:
    - name: listener_https
      address:
        socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: **** }
      # A single listener filter exists for TLS inspector.
      listener_filters:
        - name: "envoy.filters.listener.tls_inspector"
          typed_config:
            "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.listener.tls_inspector.v3.TlsInspector
      # On the listener, there is a single filter chain that matches SNI for acme.com.
      filter_chains:
        - filter_chain_match:
          transport_socket:
            name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.DownstreamTlsContext
              common_tls_context:
                tls_certificates:
                  - certificate_chain:
                      { filename: "/etc/envoy/***" }
                    private_key:
                      { filename: "/etc/envoy/***" }

          filters:
            # The HTTP connection manager is the only network filter.
            - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
              typed_config:
                "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
                codec_type: auto
                stat_prefix: ingress_http
                route_config:
                  name: local_route
                  virtual_hosts:
                    - name: echo_service
                      domains: ["*"]
                      routes:
                        - match: { prefix: "/" }
                          route:
                            cluster: echo_service
                            timeout: 0s
                            max_stream_duration:
                              grpc_timeout_header_max: 0s
                      cors:
                        allow_origin_string_match:
                          - prefix: "*"
                        allow_methods: GET, PUT, DELETE, POST, OPTIONS
                        allow_headers: keep-alive,user-agent,cache-control,content-type,content-transfer-encoding,custom-header-1,x-accept-content-transfer-encoding,x-accept-response-streaming,x-user-agent,x-grpc-web,grpc-timeout
                        max_age: "1728000"
                        expose_headers: custom-header-1,grpc-status,grpc-message
                # CustomFilter and the HTTP router filter are the HTTP filter chain.
                http_filters:
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.grpc_web
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.grpc_web.v3.GrpcWeb
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.cors
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.cors.v3.Cors
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.router
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.router.v3.Router

  clusters:
    - name: echo_service
      connect_timeout: 2.00s
      type: logical_dns
      http2_protocol_options: {}
      lb_policy: round_robin
      load_assignment:
        cluster_name: echo_service
        endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
              - endpoint:
                  address:
                    socket_address:
                      address: ****
                      port_value: ****

I have also tried the same functionality using direct http/2 request from local without making use of envoy proxy server and I am able to make more than 6 connection over there. So there must be some issue with envoy proxy itself.

I figured out why this issue is, it is because the browser itself only allows 6 parallel requests.
https://docs.diffusiondata.com/cloud/latest/manual/html/designguide/solution/support/connection_limitations.html
https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/issues/814
